# Not getting 'Cutting the Cord' Hat

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

I voted at least 10 times on my Android app last night. Is there a known bug with this hat?

Comment: Were all your votes on Stack Overflow posts?

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes they were

Comment: OK. In my experience, it may take a couple of minutes for the hat to be awarded, but not as long as you describe. Can you try again?

Comment: I'll give it another shot today

Comment: Just another thought since it always seems to come up as a source of confusion - were you actually using the Stack Exchange app?  Or just the mobile view of SO in your phone's browser?

Comment: I was using the StackOverflow Client App

Comment: Of course, you're upvoting questions that are worth it, not random junk just to get the hat, right?

Comment: Well yes.. but even if not would that actually be a factor?

Comment: Well, if it could be a factor then it would mean we have an algorithm to detect good questions, and therefore humans wouldn't have to vote anymore. So no, it probably isn't.

Comment: Or suspicious voting patterns are flagged and put in a manual queue for future review but I got the point ;)

Comment: I'm not getting the "Voted on Meta" hat even though I voted on at least five Meta posts, this one included, before I even knew that the Winter Bash had started.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After trying on a few different venues it came through. The last attempt was to use the actual **StackExchange App** vs the *StackOverflow Client App* that I had been previously trying

Comment: I have use `stack exchange android app` version 1.0.89, but without any results (